# How does SQL Server determine the order of the columns when you do a `SELECT *`?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

How does SQL Server determine the order of the columns when you do a `SELECT *`?

I know "Order By" is essential for ordering the *data*, but I expected the *column names* to be consistent.

Note: My code is *not* dependent on the actual order the columns are returned.  I just want to know how SQL Server decides to order the column names.

Of about 20 computers my team is using, one of them behaves differently. Any difference deserves to be investigated. The column name ordering appears to be the same for all computers when we open SQL Server Management Studio.  When our application makes a query is when I see the difference.

I am using SQL Server 2008, and SQL Server 2008 R2.  My application uses C# System.Data.SqlClient to access the database.

EDIT: 
My problem turned out to be that one of the computers was configured to log in as 'sa', instead of the intended user. The query was hitting the table directly when we intended it to hit a view.  Thanks for the help learning about sys.columns

Comment: well first things first, you should always specify the columns and not use SELECT *, then you can control it

Comment: it is in the order in whatever order you define them while creating the table

Comment: @bluefeet and others, this isn't a matter of best practice. It's a question of curiosity regarding how SQL Server makes certain decisions.

Comment: @bluefeet While I agree with you for the most part, it is more helpful to give a reason for statements like that, or provide a link to something that explans it. Like almost all rules there are exceptions, Why would you not use select * from a temporary table that only contains the columns needed and no others, or from a view?

Comment: @Devjosh - That's not true.  The order can be changed after that.

Comment: @Dems thanks i came to know that later

Comment: @GarethD: What if that view changes, adding unexpected columns? Never use SELECT * for production code.

Comment: One case to NOT specify the columns: A test system that logs everything from the database. By comparing today's results yesterday's results (filtered) I can detect ANY change to the system, including new columns added.

Comment: @HardCode What if a column name changes, this will be equally problematic if column names are explicitly defined? Like I said, I mostly agree, and would advocate explicitly listing columns for most production code, but it is important to provide reasons for opinions. Simply stating "Never use select *" does not really assist anyone.

Comment: @GarethD: Changing a column name is both less likely and higher impact than adding a column. Changing a column name will already have you updating T-SQL and application code. Adding a column does not always have this high impact; you may not need to change any existing T-SQL or code - only add some. I still say never use SELECT *.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They are in the order of `column_id` from the system view `sys.columns`.

You can check it by:

```
SELECT column_id, name
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = Object_id('MyTableName')
ORDER BY column_id
```

**EDIT**

This is for Dems.  You should test on a larger table, but it looks like it uses the order defined in the table, not the index:

```
CREATE TABLE #T (cola int, colb int, colc int)

INSERT INTO #T
VALUES
(1,2,3),
(2,3,4),
(4,5,6)

SELECT * FROM #T

CREATE INDEX ix_test ON #T (colb, colc, cola)

SELECT * FROM #t
WHERE colb > 0

DROP TABLE #T
```

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Great answer +1

Comment: @Yuck system views contain the answers to all lifes questions, you just have to know where to look!

Comment: If the table had a covering index across all fields, but with the fields in a different order, and that index was used to resolve the query, would this answer still hold true?

Comment: @Dems covering as in `INCLUDE`d or as in key columns?

Comment: Well, either really.  Just wondered if I could throw a spanner in the works :)  Devil's advocate-esque ;)

Comment: @Dems Looks to be consistent on a small test table - it's in the order defined in `sys.columns`.  I'll post some test code.

Comment: @JNK Does a select * where id in (...sub query...) use the same sys.columns to order the column names in the result?  If so, then I don't know why one of my machines gives different results.

Comment: @aaaabbbb It shouldn't, but if you are using `SELECT <stuff> FROM (subquery)` then the order in the `subquery` will affect it.

Comment: One of our computers was configured to use 'sa' instead of the intended account. It used the raw table, not a view.

Comment: dude. I didn't know about: `Object_id('MyTableName')` you are the bomb. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

They will be the same order in which they appear in Sql Server Management Studio; essentially, the order in which they were created.

The "correct" solution for assuring a desired column order is to specify the fields explicitly in your SELECT statement.  `SELECT *` makes no guarantees about the ordering of output columns.

Comment: So that comes from `sys.columns`? There used to be a field called `ORDINAL_POSITION` so that would have made sense. But I believe that was removed - at least from the DMVs.

Comment: @Yuck `ORDINAL_POSITION` is still in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.